# Do I need a htaccess to be able to use this module?

Tags: .htaccess, boost, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal on a Windows/IIS7 environment.  According to the Boost 7.x installation instructions (https://www.drupal.org/node/1459690), Boost will not work without .htaccess but Windows/IIS7 uses web.config not .htacess.  I can use the genrated .htacess rules and put them in web.config--this is not mentioned in the instructions.

The reason I am bringing this up is because Boost is not working well and I wonder if it is due to the .htaccess existence requirement.  It takes time to show changes to a page that is listing taxonomy terms and I believe saving a new/modified term is supposed to clear cache on save.  Clearing all caches via Drupal GUI or drush is a manual solution but I think cache clearing should happen automatically on save.

Is the .htaccess file required for Boost on Windows/IIS7 to work correctly even though IIS7 cannot use it?

Thanks

Comment: `.htaccess` is a file used by the Apache webserver. The syntax differs from `web.config` and I would not advice you to put the contents in that file. According to the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost), Boost does partially support IIS. Did you follow [this documentation step](https://www.drupal.org/node/1621192)?

Comment: Can someone help me understand why this question was migrated from Drupal Answers to SO? It's a primarily a question about how to configure a server for Drupal, the programming elements are minimal.

Comment: Why was this question moved from Drupal Answers to Stack Overflow?  It's not so much a question about .htaccess as it is a question about the Drupal Boost module's requirements.

Comment: acrosman, we both asked that question at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

[Boost can be run on IIS](https://www.drupal.org/node/1621192), but the configuration directions are a bit different. If boost is already working in other conditions, and a manual cache clear resolves your issues it is likely *not* related to boost itself.

In Drupal 7 taxonomy clears all caches when you update the vocabulary but *not* when you update a term. A term update only clears the taxonomy module's static and controller caches, leaving a large number of other caches intact. Since term changes are assumed to be much more common than a vocabulary update, and you don't want to flush caches too often, this is a reasonably set of assumptions for general case performance.

Depending on how your taxonomy term pages are setup there are other caches in play including the Views cache and Boost's cache. The cache clear in term save will not trigger `hook_flush_caches()` (the way boost would need to detect the cache clear in this case).  The view that generates the term page may also have caching enabled that's time based and so that page will remain cached as well.

There are a few ways to address the issue:

- Use the [expire module](https://www.drupal.org/project/expire) to provide a higher level of cache clearing granularity.
- Write a [`hook_taxnonmy_term_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_update/7.x) and [`hook_taxonomy_term_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7.x) to trigger boost directly (or via a [`cache_clear_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x)).

Comment: Thanks acrosman.  I assume cache will not be cleared if I move a term under another and save.  If Boost is working will I see `<!— Page cached by Boost…` in the served file?  Even though I see this line in the cache file in Boost's cache directory I don't see it on the page that is served. Do you also know if  Boost under Windows/IIS requires the generated htaccess rules to be put in web.config?  Thanks